# How do I use the .get() method to get an item in a list that is inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this

```
car = {'certificates': [{'exp_date':'1928'}]}

x = car.get("certificates"[0][0])

print(x)
```

I want to get '1928' but it prints out none.... I tried searching other posts but haven't found exactly that nor something similar to it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a `list` of `dict`, so to get 1928 you'd have to access the inner dict with `car["certificates"][0]["exp_date"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dict.get` function expects a key and a default value and returns the value associated to the key from the dictionary if it exists otherwise. (You find the documentation of the function directly in Python with `help(dict.get)`)

We can try to get how the important line of your code works step by step:

```
"certificates" # The literal string "certificates"
"certificates"[0] # The first character of "certificates" which is "c"
"certificates"[0][0] # The first character of "c" which is "c"
car.get("certificates"[0][0]) # The value corresponding to "c" which does not exist, so the default None
```

The correct way to achieve what you want would be:

```
"certificates" # The literal string "certificates"
car.get("certificates") # The value of "certificates" in car which is [{'exp_date':'1928'}]
car.get("certificates")[0] # The first value in [{'exp_date':'1928'}] which is {'exp_date':'1928'}
car.get("certificates")[0]["exp_date"] # The value corresponding to "exp_date" in {'exp_date':'1928'} which is 1928
```

**Addendum**: What happens when something goes wrong?

The `get` function does not raise an error in the case that the key does not exist but instead returns the default value, so you have to ask yourself in which cases you want an error and in which do you want a default value

1. Get an error when there is no certificate or no expiration date:
   `car["certificates"][0]["exp_date"]`
2. Get default value (let's say 0) if there is a certificate but an error if the certificate lacks an expiration date
   `car.get("certificate", [{"exp_date": 0}])[0]["exp_date"]`
3. Get an error if there is no certificate but a default value if certificate lacks an expiration date
   `car["certificate"][0].get("exp_date", 0)`
4. Get a default value in both cases
   `car.get("certificate", [{}])[0].get("exp_date", 0)`

What this should make clear is that `car.get("certificates")[0]["exp_date"]` is closest to what you wrote but does not make sense, because in the case that there is no certificate `car.get("certificate")` returns `None` and then you get an error when evaluating `None[0]`. So with option number 1 you also get an error in this case but with an error message that is actually meaningful.

Comment: Outstanding answer! Thank you. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

**This works:**

```
car = {'certificates': [{'exp_date':'1928'}]}

x = car.get('certificates')[0].get('exp_date')

print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this:

```
x = car.get("certificates"[0][0])
```

to this (no need to use `get`):

```
x = car["certificates"][0]["exp_date"]
```

`dict`s are indexed by key, not number (unless the key is a number). What you were doing, is indexing it as if it was a `list`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this was a simplified example to convey what I'm trying to do. In reality I'm parsing a json file so .get() is vital as many times the data is not the same and null values are returned causing an error.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use get here, you can just use:

```
car = {'certificates': [{'exp_date':'1928'}]}

x = car['certificates'][0]['exp_date']
#
#with get: car.get('certificates')[0].get('exp_date')

print(x)
```

Output:

```
1928
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this was a simplified example to convey what I'm trying to do. In reality I'm parsing a json file so .get() is vital as many times the data is not the same and null values are returned causing an error.